# OpenLayers 3 - Source with multiple available projections

Tags: openlayers-3

Is there anyway to specify a (Tile)WMS source that supports multiple projections?

For example, my WMS server supports requests for both EPSG:4326 and EPSG:3395. So if the projection is supported in server-side, the tiles are requested with the appropriate projection, else OpenLayers tries to reproject one of the supported projections.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the client side reprojection to do that, see this [example](http://openlayers.org/en/master/examples/reprojection.html) .

Just add a `projection` property to your `ol.source.TileWms`.

Comment: The point here is to leverage server-side projections when available. Eventually went with swapping sources at runtime.

Comment: You can use the WMS GetCapabilities to get the projections available in your WMS.

Comment: I know what projections are available in advance, my question was how to change the Source projection in openlayers so the tiles are requested with the correct SRS/CRS parameter.